# play the garden

Tags: meaning

> “You know,” I said to Rupert, “under Islamic law a quintessentially English occasion like this one would probably be outlawed.” Rupert
>   nodded. **He played the garden some more**, a glass of white wine in
>   his hand. Then it was time for him to make a speech about Omar Bakri.
>   He took his place next to the raffle stall, and the garden fell
>   silent.

Extract from Jon Ronson, *Them: Adventures with Extremists*

Will you help me with understanding the meaning of the phrase "play the garden" in the sentence above. Neither literal nor metaphorical meaning does not make me sense.

Comment: Who is *he* in *He played he garden some more,...?* Rupert or I or someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a combination of two phrases "work the room" and "play to the crowd", which have similar meanings:

*[Work the room](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/work_the_room)*:

> (idiomatic, of a host, hostess, or guest) To interact enthusiastically with the attendees at an event, by moving among them, greeting them, and engaging them in conversation.
>   *As a campaigning politician, he really knew how to shake hands, kiss babies, and work the room.*
>
> (idiomatic, of a performer or public speaker) To interact with one's audience, taking cues from its reactions and adapting one's performance or words to elicit the audience's attention and enthusiasm.

[Play to the crowd](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+to+the+gallery):

> to perform in a manner that will get the strong approval of the audience; to perform in a manner that will get the approval of the lower elements in the audience.
>    - *John is a competent actor, but he has a tendency to play to the crowd.*
>    - *When he made the rude remark, he was just playing to the gallery.*

So, in this case, the subjects are outside, in a garden, so they can't "work the room", they need to "work the garden". And it's not uncommon to switch "work" and "play".

Comment: A related phrase is "work the room."

Comment: @mkennedy OMG... I've been going crazy because I can't find "play the room" in google and you're completely right. the normal phrase is "work the room".